# Manually scheduled task is moved in time but it shouldn't. Why is that?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, ms-project

I expected that manualy scheduled tasks will not change their dates automatically despite of all other things happened in the project. My Boss says that meeting will be at some fixed date. All previous and later tasks must adjust to that date.

Manipulating the task dates prior to the meeting dates constantly change the fixed dates of the meetings "over and over". I must still remember that the meeting dates might be changed without notice. And what if I have 5 meetings in my project?

That behaviour makes lots of dalay in my work on my project. It takes me as lot as 1 working day of work to prepare 40 task's project.

Help me with this, please. It seems my work is not effective. Why is that?

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the kind of constraint. There are

- Flexible
- Semi-Flexible
- Inflexible

I'd assume you're using a semi-flexible constraint while you really want to use an inflexible one. Microsoft's online help describes [constraints](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/set-a-start-date-or-finish-date-constraint-for-a-task-HA010113073.aspx) in detail - this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing that you are using MS Project 2010, which introduces "Manually scheduled tasks" as a separate concept to "Auto-scheduled tasks with inflexible constraints".

Under the Options dialog -> Schedule tab -> Section labelled "Scheduling options for this project", look for a check box that is labelled "Update Manually Scheduled tasks when editing links". If this box is checked, that may result in manually scheduled tasks being moved around as you described, so make sure that it is unchecked.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Like the creator of this thread and probably anybody else I would've expected that a manual set date would never change automatically. What's even worse that it often happens unnoticed... Glad I found your answer, thank you so much!